# PHP session not transferring through frame redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have a website set up for people to sign up for a small event.

After pressing submit on the
index.php I start my functions to insert their data into my DB and depending on if it works or not, set a session variable with the result in it. Like this:

part of the function:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "That worked, thank you!";
header("location:thankyou.php") 
exit();
```

on the thankyou.php I do echo it like this:

```
<?php  echo "<div id='content'><h1>".$_SESSION['message']."</h1></div>"; ?>
```

Everything works locally.

Everything works hosted on my webspace.

But as this is an event for a students council, I did a frame redirect (to keep their domain in the browsers adressbar) to my domain. At this point, the session gets lost after I submit an entry. The thankyou.php stays empty.

I tried to check for the $_SESSION with a var_dump(), but it is completely empty.

Any hints on how to transfer the $_SESSION array while keeping the frame redirect would be really appreciated!

EDIT: session_start() is already there on every file.

Comment: add session_start() in the thankyou.php file

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but session_start() is already there on every file. And as I said it works locally and on my webspace, but not when redirected to from another domain.

Comment: Do this fail in all browsers? Safari do have some strange behavior with not allowing cookies to be set in iframes. You can also check the request to see if the same session id is sent with each request to check if it is a cookie problem

Comment: I just installed chrome and it works there. Do you have any hints for a workaround for safari here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you can regard the `iframe` as a new browser window, now displayed within the same page. You said:

> I did a frame redirect (to keep their domain in the browsers adressbar) to my domain.

Which means you try to fool the user a bit. The way sessions usually work is with an session identifier that PHP uses to retrieve the session data. So either:

1. the session ID is not passed correctly (perhaps due to safety restrictions), you better check this first, use `session_id()` or the devtools from the browser to monitor http requests. It's possible that using the `Location:` header does not pass the session ID, it might even be browser specific.
2. the main window sets the session ID, there might be a mismatch between how sessions are stored in the `iframe` and the main window. First thing to check is the configuration.

Comment: It seems to be browser specific. Only safari makes the issue appear. For the sake of simplicity I made the output on the index.php without any session magic. The project is too small to put too much effort in it. I looked into you suggestions and I think that the behaviour is safari-specific and therefore not easily fixable. Thank you!